# build REST API for WooCommerce for mobile apps

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-rest-api

we are building the REST API for WooCommerce and we want to add a product to user's cart. For that we have used Cart API for WooCommerce but it doesn't seems to working for us as it doesn't giving any option to set user_id along with the data so we are facing issues with mobile app and website syncing. We want to make it generalize like if user is using mobile and adds product to cart, it should be remain in the cart if login from web too and it's seems not working for us

Any help will be appreciated for it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this? I am  also looking for the same, want to add product to user's cart from mobile app and that should be sync with website. Please let me know if you have found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Woo-commerce cart items is temporary  store in session so you can not get items using REST API, for that you have to make a `custom table` of cart then store details in your `custom cart table` using REST API.

Comment: okay. so how can I display that product to the website if the same user logs in? 
Do you have any idea about it?